# Dajngo admin ModelForm: how to get request and/or user loggin in my form to filter queryset?

Tags: python, django, admin, keyword-argument

I have a custom User class with a property that return a queryset
And I have an Admin class that use a custom ModelForm with 2 ModelChoiceField and fone BooleanFields.

I want to filter queryset of one ModelChoiceField using user property
but my problem is that I do not have access to request or user in my ModelForm.
I try to use method get_form_kwargs I use for 'normal CBV' but it doen't work as this method do not exist in ModelAdmin

**admin.py**

```
class User_TableAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super(User_TableAdmin,self).__init__(model,admin_site)
        self.form.admin_site = admin_site # capture the admin_site


    form = User_TableAdminForm            **# How to request object to my form?**
    list_display = ('id','user','table','can_download')
    search_fields = ('user','table','can_download')
```

**forms.py**

```
class User_TableAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super(User_TableAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # add the 'green +' button to create a new user (green + button suppress when overidding field with ModelChoiceField) 
        self.fields['user'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            self.fields['user'].widget, 
            self.instance._meta.get_field('user').remote_field, 
            admin_site)


    class Meta:
        model = User_Table
        fields = '__all__'

    # display only tables of study database that user workin: User property
    # tables = self.user.can_download
    tables = Table.objects.all() **#<- I would like to use something like request.user.can_download**

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.all(), label = "User", widget = forms.Select())
    table = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = tables, label = "Table", widget = forms.Select())
    can_download = forms.BooleanField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxInput(),
        required = False,
    )
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="database")
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


    @property
    def can_download(self):
        """ Return the related list of tables use can download. """
        

        return Table.objects.filter(
            Q(database__study__in = [uss.study.id for uss in User_Site_Study.objects.filter(user = self.id)]) &
            Q(database__study__is_opened = True) &
            Q(database__is_opened = True)
        )

    can_download.fget.short_description = 'List of tables user allowed to download'
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can override `ModelAdmin.get_form()` which returns the `ModelForm` *class* that will be used in add or change admin page and decorate it to inject request upon creation of form instance.

```py
class ModelFormWithRequest(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def inject_request(cls, request):
        def __new__(_, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.setdefault('request', request)
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return type(
            f'{cls.__name__}Decorator',
            (cls,),
            {
                '__module__': cls.__module__,
                '__doc__': cls.__doc__, 
                '__new__': __new__
            }
        )


class User_TableAdminForm(ModelFormWithRequest):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelFormWithRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['table'].queryset = # set new queryset filtered with self.request.user data
        # add the 'green +' button to create a new user (green + button suppress when overidding field with ModelChoiceField) 
        self.fields['user'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            self.fields['user'].widget, 
            self.instance._meta.get_field('user').remote_field, 
            admin_site)


class User_TableAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    form = User_TableAdminForm
    list_display = ('id','user','table','can_download')
    search_fields = ('user','table','can_download')

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super(User_TableAdmin,self).__init__(model,admin_site)
        self.form.admin_site = admin_site # capture the admin_site

    # this is how you pass request to form
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        ModelForm = super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs))
        # pass request only to change form, it assumes this is a subclass of auth.UserAdmin
        if change:
            return ModelForm.inject_request(request)
        return ModelForm
```

just to extend answer, if one needs to pass request to `InlineModelAdmin`'s forms, which is handled by formsets, need to override `get_formset()` instead of `get_form()`

```py
class CustomInlineModelAdmin(admin.InlineModelAdmin):

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset_class = super().get_formset(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
        formset_class.form = formset_class.form.inject_request(request)
        return formset_class
```

There is a shorter solution, just set `ModelForm.request = request` in `ModelAdmin.get_form()`. In this case `ModelFormWithRequest` is not needed, but I prefer to pass dynamic dependencies though constructor instead of appending it to class objects which are global.